# Lambda Serverless Nodejs - Getting "Internal server error" when callback is called inside a promise

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, es6-promise, serverless, serverless-framework-offline

### I am trying to call the `callback(null,response)` inside `.then()` block of a promise. It works fine when i am using [serverless offline](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/) but its giving error when using [serverless](https://serverless.com/).

There are two scenarios:

#### 1 Works fine (when deployed using `serverless deploy` and when using `sls offline start`)

```
module.exports.getAssembly = (event, context, callback) => {

        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!'
            }),
        };
        callback(null, response)


}
```

#### 2 Works fine with `sls offline` but gives `internal server error` with `serverless deploy`

```
module.exports.getAssembly = (event, context, callback) => {


    mysql.query('SELECT * from assemblies',connection).then((returnedObject)=>{
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: returnedObject.results
            }),
        };
        callback(null, response)

    })

}
```

There is some problem with the `callback(null,response)` inside the `.then()` block of the `promise`

Comment: add catch block and check.

Comment: On my machine, i am using .catch() block. Also, verified the logs, its going inside the .then() block only.

Comment: can you post the Cloudwatch logs for the call?

Comment: CloudWatch logs:
START RequestId: xxxx Version: $LATEST
2018-02-27T06:31:09.623Z xxxx {timeStamp: 2018-02-27T06:31:09.623Z , log:' Request For query -> SELECT * from assemblies '}

2018-02-27T06:31:09.674Z xxxx {timeStamp: 2018-02-27T06:31:09.674Z , log:' Query result success '}

END RequestId: xxxx

REPORT RequestId: xxxx Duration: 6006.15 ms Billed Duration: 6000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 27 MB
 
2018-02-27T06:31:15.626Z xxxx Task timed out after 6.01 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` solves the problem.